# Error: Individual stylesheets must be in the sass directory

Tags: sass, compass-sass, ionic-framework, gulp

My CSS doesn't work. Here is my terminal log:

```
$ gulp sass
Using gulpfile ~/dev/myproject/gulpfile.js
Starting 'sass-ionic'...
Starting 'sass-myproject'...
Individual stylesheets must be in the sass directory.

{ [Error: Compass failed]
  message: 'Compass failed',
  fileName: '/Users/me/dev/myproject/scss/main.scss',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'gulp-compass',
  __safety: { toString: [Function] } }
Finished 'sass-ionic' after 634 ms
```

I am using Ionic Framework.

The funny part is that I have two computers with pretty much same setup and the other works fine and the other gives the error above. I'm using git so the both projects have identical files and folder structure.

EDIT: After downgrading compass:

Here is what I get after 'gulp sass':

```
Starting 'sass-ionic'...
Starting 'sass-murikka'...
Finished 'sass-ionic' after 614 ms
  warning Webkit only supports pixels for the start and end stops for radial gradients. Got: 100%
  warning Webkit only supports pixels for the start and end stops for radial gradients. Got: 100%
identical ./www/css/main.css 

Finished 'sass-murikka' after 843 ms
Starting 'sass'...
Finished 'sass' after 13 μs
```

On the other computer I get exactly the same output except

```
identical ./www/css/main.css
```

-->

```
overwrite ./www/css/main.css
```

Comment: Which version of `compass` are you using? Have you tried to update?

Comment: compass-1.0.1
I uninstalled it and installed compass-0.12.7 which resolved the problem!

Comment: Will post this answer then

Comment: @MikaVäisänen Downgrading to 0.12 doesn't seem like a very useful solution for users who require features from Sass 3.3+ (which aren't compatible with Compass 0.12).

Comment: Sorry, the problem actually still exists. Now there are no error and it generates main.min.css file but the page looks like there's no CSS, just plain text. I have compass-0.12.7 installed on my other computer which works fine.

Comment: The path to the css file is the same? Is there a 404 error?

Comment: The path is the same and there are no 404 error. Status code for main.min.css is 304.

Comment: Here is what I get after 'gulp sass':

Starting 'sass-ionic'...
Starting 'sass-murikka'...
 Finished 'sass-ionic' after 614 ms
  warning Webkit only supports pixels for the start and end stops for radial gradients. Got: 100%
  warning Webkit only supports pixels for the start and end stops for radial gradients. Got: 100%
identical ./www/css/main.css 

Finished 'sass-murikka' after 843 ms
Starting 'sass'...
Finished 'sass' after 13 μs

On the other computer I get exactly the same output except  'identical ./www/css/main.css' --> 'overite ./www/css/main.css'

Comment: And have you upgraded the `sass` gem too?

Comment: sass -v is 3.4.9. On the other computer it's 3.2.19. I tried to downgrade it aswell, but nothing changed. By the way, I am using rvm gemset.

Comment: And there is nothing in the resulting CSS file? Have you checked if your files are properly processed by your task?

Comment: Surprisingly the resulting CSS file looks fine. I updated

Comment: It seems to be a bug but I don't know how to fix it. https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1769

Answer (score 0):

For anybody stumbling across this bug on a Windows environment, first check your config paths to ensure they're not absolute or some other nonsense.

Next, make sure you use the correct case with your directories when navigating to your project directory. Since Windows is case-insensitive, it will allow you to `cd myproject/source/` when it's actually `MyProject/source/`. `gulp-compass` will give this error if you run your gulp task using just `cd myproject/source/` lower case.

Check your terminal CWD and make sure it matches the case: `$ MyProject/source/ > gulp sass` or some such.

Answer (score -1):

Check if Ruby is installed in your computer. I had the same error and installing ruby solved the problem

Comment: I got mac. It has ruby pre-installed.